# Rally Rest Api - DynamicJsonObject how to check if key exists

Tags: rally

I am trying to display a list of stories (hierarchical requirements) and defects from Rally on a web page.

We have a custom field called "InfraID" on our defects, but not on our hierarchical requirements.  Is there a way of detecting whether each DynamicJsonObject has a key called "InfraId" to avoid it throwing an exception?

I've tried TryGetValue, Contains, HasKey thinking it was being treated as a dictionary but I keep getting a KeyNotFoundException. "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

This is being used in a Razor ASP.NET MVC view.

```
@if (story.HasKey("InfraID"))
    {
       <td>@story["InfraID"];
       </td>
    }
```

So I can't figure out what that if statement can be to avoid an exception being thrown.  Story is of type Rally.RestAPI.DynamicJsonObject.

I'm trying to use the same html whether its a defect or a story, as everything else has worked ok.  It's just because it's a custom attribute on a defect.

In case it helps the stack trace that seems relevant is:

```
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Rally.RestApi.DynamicJsonObject.GetMember(String name)
   at Rally.RestApi.DynamicJsonObject.TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, Object& result)
```

So I'm hoping that doesn't mean I can't check for its existence in my front end code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [HasMember](https://docs.rallydev.com/restapinet/html/M_Rally_RestApi_DynamicJsonObject_HasMember.htm):

`bool hasInfraId = story.HasMember("InfraID");`

You can find the methods/namespace for Rally.RestApi.DynamicJsonObject in the full api docs out on the developer portal here:

[Rally REST API .NET Namespace](https://docs.rallydev.com/restapinet/html/N_Rally_RestApi.htm)

Comment: That's great thanks.  Will add that link to my bookmarked rally pages too :)